# List and filter from data model based on user selection - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

**OUTLINE**

I have 3 lists in 3 `VStacks` based from a data model.

1. Categories
2. Applications
3. Products

The idea is that when the user selects a **category**, it filters through the **application** list and only displays **applications** that are found in the same data model. Then when the user selects an **application** from the second list, it would only list **products** found in the same data model into the third column.

**PROBLEM**

I am struggling to filter and list the **applications** based on the selected **category**. Once I know how to do that I am assuming I can use the same method to filter the final **products** column.

**CODE**

```
struct ProductModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var headerTitle: String
    var categories: [String]
    var application: [String]  
}

let productData: [ProductModel] = [
    ProductModel(
        headerTitle: "product1",
        categories: ["All", "Mercury analyser"],
        application: ["All", "Beverages","Chemicals", "Clinical", "Gin", "Cosmetics", "Energy","Environmental", "Food", "Gas"]
    ),
    ProductModel(
        headerTitle: "product2",
        categories: ["All", "Microwave digestion"],
        application: ["All", "Gin","Metals","Polymers"],
    ),
    ProductModel(
        headerTitle: "product3",
        categories: ["All", "Microwave digestion"],
        application: ["All", "Gin","Metals","Polymers", "Clinical", "Food", "Cosmetics"],
    ),
]

class SelectedState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedCategory = "All"
    @Published var selectedApplication = "All"
    @Published var selectedProduct = ""
}

struct ProductList3: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var selected = SelectedState()
    
    var products: [ProductModel] = productData
    var categories =  Array(Set(productData.flatMap(\.categories)))
        .sorted { (a: String, b: String) -> Bool in  a == "All" ? true : b == "All" ? false : a < b }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                // SELECT CATEGORY
                ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selected.selectedCategory = item
                    })
                    {
                        Text(item) // LIST CATEGORIES
                    }
                }
                // FILTER APPLICATIONS BASED ON WHICH CATERGORY WAS SELECTED
                VStack {
                    let matchedItems = products.filter { product in
                        let list = product.categories
                        let count = product.application.count
                        for item in list {
                            if item == selected.selectedCategory {
                                return true
                            }
                        }
                        return false
                    }

                    ForEach(matchedItems) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                        self.selected.selectedCategory = item
                    })
                    {
                        Text(item) // LIST APPLICATIONS
                    }
                }
                // FILTER PRODUCTS BASED ON APPLICATION SELECTED
                VStack {
                    // DISPLAY ALL PRODUCTS THAT MATCH FILTERS
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.contains` method will work well for your usage. You can filter the products based on whether or not their `categories` or `applications` contain a selected item.

I also used a couple of other techniques from your original code, like using `Set` to filter out duplicate elements and your `sorted` method to put `All` at the top (I moved it to its own extension to be able to reuse it).

```
struct ProductList3: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var selected = SelectedState()
    
    var products: [ProductModel] = productData
    var categories =  Array(Set(productData.flatMap(\.categories)))
        .sortedWithAll()
    
    var activeApplications : Set<String> {
        Set(products.flatMap { product -> [String] in
            if product.categories.contains(selected.selectedCategory) {
                return product.application
            } else {
                return []
            }
        })
    }
    
    var activeProducts : Set<String> {
        Set(
            products.filter { $0.application.contains(selected.selectedApplication) }.map { $0.headerTitle }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selected.selectedCategory = item
                    })
                    {
                        Text(item) // LIST CATEGORIES
                            .foregroundColor(item == selected.selectedCategory ? Color.red : Color.accentColor)
                    }
                }
                
                Divider()
                
                ForEach(Array(activeApplications).sortedWithAll(), id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        selected.selectedApplication = item
                    }) {
                        Text(item)
                            .foregroundColor(item == selected.selectedApplication ? Color.red : Color.accentColor)
                    }
                }
                
                Divider()
                
                ForEach(Array(activeProducts), id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element == String {
    func sortedWithAll() -> [String] {
        return self.sorted { (a: String, b: String) -> Bool in  a == "All" ? true : b == "All" ? false : a < b }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for you answer and simplifying the code

Comment: Sorry - I have worked it out now. Thank you for your help